# error on populating a SQL table from java

Tags: java, jdbc, insert

I have this query and I don't understand why I get an error.
**Error:** com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'from, to, subject) VALUES ('me','you','Missed you!')' at line 1

```
 String from = "me";
 String to = "you";
 String subject = "Missed you!";


 String query = "INSERT INTO emailApp (from, to, subject) VALUES ('"+from+"','"+to+"','"+subject+"')";
        st.executeUpdate(query);
```

Comment: `from` is SQL keyword, you need to prefix it with the name of the table, something like `emailApp.from` might work.  You should also be using a `PreparedStatement`, see [Using Prepared Statements](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html) for more details...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`FROM`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysqld-version-reference/en/mysqld-version-reference-reservedwords-5-5.html) and `TO` are SQL reserved keywords. ALTER both column names in the database and adjust your query to match the new name.

```
PreparedStatement prepareStatement = 
    connection.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO emailApp (sender, recipient, subject) VALUES (?, ?, ?)");
prepareStatement.setInt(1, sender);
prepareStatement.setInt(2, recipient);
prepareStatement.setInt(3, subject);
prepareStatement.executeUpdate();
```

Comment: String query = "INSERT INTO emailApp (sender, to, subject) VALUES ('"+sender+"','"+to+"','"+subject+"')"; - Still is not working.

Comment: `TO` is also a reserved word

Comment: do I need to add data to all the fields? Because it keep saying that a certain field doesn't have a default value.

Answer (score 0):

```
 String from = "me";
 String to = "you";
 String subject = "Missed you!";

 String query = "INSERT INTO emailApp ("columnName1", "columnName2", "columnName3") VALUES ('"+from+"','"+to+"','"+subject+"')";
    st.executeUpdate(query);
```

Comment: I prefer to use apis as hibernate, etc. Just trying to help the ringer on your error. Insurance is starting on this.